# How to get a total amount of products in children categories of single parent

Tags: laravel

I have a Category model in which has children categories which has products... getting the total amount of products along with the children is easy. But what about getting the parent categories total amount which is the sum of all children categories of this single parent?

Here is the App\Category model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function scopeTotalShirts($query)
{
    return $query->where('slug', 'shirts')->first()->children->each->products()->count();
}
```

A shirt would have child categories such as T-Shirt, Long Sleeve, Graphic, etc.

I want to get the total of those children categories so it all adds up in the Shirts (parent) category.

Is there some elegant way to do this besides querying up the children categories and getting the count?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer you can remove the extra queries in the loop, at the least:

```
$children = $category->children()->withCount('products')->get();

return $children->sum('products_count');
```

Or you can do the actual query from the inverse direction and remove the need for all of this:

```
return Product::whereHas('child.category', function ($q) {
    $q->where('slug', 'shirts');
})->count();
```

Though, I don't know how you setup these relationships in the inverse.

---

Based on the relationships you have you probably need to do more querying here as I would suppose a Product could belong to a parent or child category:

```
return Product::whereHas('category', function ($q) {
    $q->where('slug', 'shirts')
        ->orWhereHas('parent', fn ($q) => $q->where('slug', 'shirts'));
})->count();
```

The `Product` model should have a `category` relationship (`belongsTo`). The `parent` relationship on `Category` should be a `belongsTo` not `hasOne`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To remove the queries from the loop, is all that I have to do is remove the () from products() to be $child->products->count();? Or does the ->count() still query through each iteration?

Comment: well there is no reason for either of those as you are not looping through these records now ... but if you don't eager load the `products` relationship you will still have just as many queries with both of those  ... it would be better to attempt to go at it from the inverse direction as it would be one query action and you would also have the result (if that works with the relationships the way they are setup); unless you actually need these records and not just the count

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to do more research on the whereHas portion. Is it faster than the first method you proposed?

Comment: I definitely only need the count in this case

Comment: i would rather the database be doing the filter for me, considering these tables could become large (though its only a single category at the moment you are looking into) and otherwise you are loading a lot of records into PHP to then just count them ... it should be more efficient but you can and **should** profile it ... just trying to look forward a lil bit

Comment: I'm having trouble defining the inverse relationship xD.... I have this so far:     public function headphones()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id')->where('category_id', 0);
    }

Comment: Hey lagbox -- I came up with this in the Product Model: public function headphoneChildren()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id')->whereIn('id', [7,8,9,10,11,12]);
    } and this in the Category model:     public static function getTotalHeadphones()
    {
        return Product::whereHas('headphoneChildren')->count();
    }... does this work okay?

Comment: Thank you so much lagbox I appreciate you, I can see this pattern being used a lot in my projects

Comment: Do you recommend I create functions for the children's count as well? Or would: {{ App\Category::where('slug', 'graphics')->first()->products->count() }} suffice?

Comment: you are loading all the product models to just count them, which isn't a good idea unless you need those records ...  i would try to not be doing a query like this in the view though

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
public static function getTotalShirts()
{
    $category = Category::where('slug', 'shirts')->first();
    $children = $category->children()->get();
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $count += $child->products()->count();
    }
    return $count;
}
```

I was wondering if there was some neater way to do it? And is having public static functions safe?

Comment: what would make it unsafe?

Comment: I'm not sure, just wondering if it's an okay method to use or if outside sources can call to the function or something

Comment: outside sources? its a public static method .... any thing can call it (public)

Comment: I mean like hackers, I guess they couldn't do anything with it anyways